# How to use two filters in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

I have input field:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="in">
```

Also select list:

```
<select ng-model="sel"></select>
```

How I can use two filters in `ng-repeat` something like:

```
ng-repeat="item in arr | filter:sel | filter:in"
```

My select list in header:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
   <select ng-controller="in"></select>
</div>
```

Also in bottom of page I have:

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">{{in}}</div>
```

But `{{in}}` is empty

Comment: You're using correct. Can you share your code where you're getting error.

Comment: Do you have value property of <option> tag set for each select <option>?

Comment: @ Kaffarov, did you check my answer below?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense; `<select ng-controller="in">` isn't even valid. also, why are you repeating `ng-controller` in another div? That div won't have access to the `$scope` of the other controller....

Comment: it would be much easier to see what is going on if you post all the relevant code from the page, and even better, if you create a plunker demonstrating your issue.  http://plnkr.co/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're doing right.
The following can be taken as an example to apply filter. You can modify it to apply multiple filters as well.

**Search field**

```
<input type="text" ng-model="in" placeholder="Enter value to search.">
<select ng-model="sel">
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

**Using filter in ng-repeat:**

```
<div>    
<tr ng-repeat="item in filteredData = (arr | filter:in | filter: sel)">
</div>
```

or simple way for multiple filters like as per your question

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in arr| filter:in | filter: sel">
```

**Then showing message whether data found or not.**

```
<div ng-show="!(filteredData ).length">
    No matching data found
</div>
```

Comment: It does not work for me. because I have two same controllers in HTML page. Updated question

Comment: what you mean by " I have two same controllers in HTML page"? it looks weired statement. Can you post your whole code?